# Trying to group up results of a SQL multi table query

Tags: php, mysql

alright best way for me to explain is by giving an example

```
Table 1
ID | name        | class
-------------------------
 1 | first name  | a
 2 | second name | b

 Table 2
 ID | name_id | meta_key    | meta_value              |
-------------------------------------------------------
 1  | 1       | image       | someImage.jpg           |
 2  | 1       | description | very long description   |
 3  | 2       | image       | someImage_2.jpg         |
 4  | 2       | description | very long description 2 |
```

I am trying to select name and class from Table 1, and also all the records from Table 2 that has the same `name_id` as ID (in Table 1).

Here is the query i have now:

```
SELECT
    table1.name,
    table1.class,
    table2.name_id,
    table2.meta_key,
    table2.meta_value                    
FROM 
    table1 
LEFT JOIN 
   table2 ON ( table1.ID = table2.name_id )           
WHERE 
   table1.ID = '2'
```

This works and return an array with as many elements as the Table 2 entries that has name_id = 2

Is there a way to return an array with 1 the result from first table, and another array with results from the second table ?

Update:
The ideal results will be:
    $result['table1'][0] = array('name' => 'second name', 
                                 'class' => 'b')

```
$result['table2'][0] = array('name_id' => 2, 
                             'meta_key' => 'image', 
                             'meta_value' => 'someImage_2.jpg')
$result['table2'][1] = array('name_id' => 2, 
                             'meta_key' => 'description', 
                             'meta_value' => 'very long description 2')
```

hopes that makes sense.

Comment: Well, that's just a SQL statement. If you want `arrays` then you're looking for PHP code. I bet it would be better to split the array rather than creating 2 separate queries

Comment: What i am asking is if there is a SQL way or a query that will return an array that has what i needed.  i know i can take the current results and make a new array that would fit what i am looking for.

Comment: What output are you trying to get? Could you make a model of that?

Comment: yea will add it to post

Comment: @NetaMeta As I said before. `Arrays` is what you handle in PHP. There can't be a way to work with arrays in SQL. It is 100% a matter of PHP and you should handle that in PHP.

Comment: so its not possible to create a SQL query that will return the results the way i intended ?

Comment: Nope. handle it in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd split the result array AFTER fetching it from the database...

```
//Assuming your result-set is assigned to $result:

$table1_keys = array('id', 'name', 'class');
$table2_keys = array('id', 'name_id', 'meta_key', 'meta_value');

$table1_results = array();
$table2_results = array();

foreach($result as $key => $val) {
    if(in_array($key, $table1_keys)) {
        $table1_results[] = $val;
    }

    if(in_array($key, $table2_keys)) {
        $table2_results[] = $val;
    }
}
```

After this, your result-set should be split into two arrays: `$table1_results` and `$table2_results`.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way to do it in SQL but I'd label each table so it can be done generically in PHP.

```
SELECT
  ':table1',
    table1.name,
    table1.class,
  ':table2',
    table2.name_id,
    table2.meta_key,
    table2.meta_value
FROM ...
```

Although personally I'd just do this.

```
SELECT 'table1', table1.*, ':table2', table2.*
FROM ...
```

That makes it easier to duplicate entire rows between client and server and reduces maintenance when you decide to add a new field.

However in your query you are duplicating table1 for each row returned so perhaps this would be better.

```
SELECT
  table1.*,
  table2a.meta_value AS image,
  table2b.meta_value AS description
FROM
  table1
LEFT JOIN
  table2 AS table2a ON ( table1.ID = table2a.name_id AND table2a.meta_key = 'image' )
LEFT JOIN
  table2 AS table2b ON ( table1.ID = table2b.name_id AND table2b.meta_key = 'description' )
WHERE 
  table1.ID = '2'
```